# Best Ruby idiom for logic like this

Tags: ruby, idioms

I've outlined two functions here.  The js_funct is a common js style and test_funct is my attempt to kind of Ruby-ize it.

Any better/alternative/cleaner/ruby-ish ways of handling this?

```
@flipped_on = true

# assume my_funct is expensive
def my_funct
  'success'
end

def test_funct
  res = my_funct if @flipped_on
  res.length if res
end

def js_funct
  if @flipped_on
    res = my_funct
    if res
      return res.length
    end
  end
  return nil
end

p test_funct
p js_funct
```

**EDIT:**

Think I might have answered my own question here.   Requires a lot of thinking to interpret this though.

```
def test_funct
  res = my_funct and res.length if @flipped_on
end
```

Comment: This single line if statement usage is great.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a common Ruby idiom for doing an expensive computation once and caching the result:

```
def expensive_function
  @expensive_function ||= compute_expensive_function
end
```

This causes compute_expensive_function to be called only once, no matter how many times expensive_function is called.

Caveat: Because this technique relies upon the short-circuit or operator, it won't work correctly for functions that return true/false (or truthy/falsy).  For that, there is the [promise gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/promise):

```
def initialize
  @expensive_function = promise {compute_expensive_function}
end

def do_something
  ...
  puts @expensive_function
  ...
end
```

The promise gem is more versatile than presented here.  Also, it comes with a `future` function, which caches the result like `promise`, but also does the computation in a separate thread, so that you can get a head-start on the expensive function:

```
def initialize
  @expensive_function = future {compute_expensive_function}
end

def do_something
  ...
  puts @expensive_function
  ...
end
```

Comment: Doesn't quite solve the exact problem. I do really like this promise gem.  Thanks.

Comment: @Steve Mc, You're welcome.  If there were a gold badge for "doesn't solve the exact problem," I'd surely have it.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say your version is quite clean and readable, except you can in fact remove the last **return nil** line, since by default a ruby function returns nil if not specified.

Or you could also write a single line for this:

```
def test_funct
  @flipped_on && (res = my_funct) && res.length || nil
end
```

If returning false is not a problem, the **|| nil** part could also be removed.

Edit: your own version is better :->

Comment: That's pretty cool though.  Crazy what can be done on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what `js_funct` should do. `res` in it is completely useless:

```
def js_funct
  if @flipped_on
    res = my_funct
    if res
      return res.length
    end
  end
  return nil
end
```

You could just say `my_funct.length` and get the length of whatever the function `my_funct` returns.

But it seems that following thing confuses you: in Ruby, functions (we call them methods, as they always belong to an object) are not first-class objects. So you can't say `res = my_funct`, hoping that you would assign a *function* to a variable, as you would in JavaScript. In Ruby, that line would first *execute* `my_funct` method, and put its *result* into variable named `res`.

If you would like to check if a method is defined, you can, for example, use [`Object#respond_to?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001005) method.

If you would like to wrap your method into an object in order to pass it around, you should use [`Object#method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001038) method. But in Ruby it's more common to pass *blocks* (closures) around, rather than whole *methods*. You are in fact doing that every time you use `map`, `each` or other common Ruby methods.

If you would want to see how a particular task is coded in Ruby, you should say what the task is. Your example doesn't tell that.

Comment: But that would mean that it would be called twice.  The assumption is that my_funct is expensive.  I want to call my_funct once, then test its result.  If not nil, then do something on its return.

Comment: And you need to assume that my_funct may be nil if it fails.  So you need handle all cases.

Comment: Ah, I missed the point of `res` then. If it's expensive operation, you should consider wrapping `my_funct` into an accessor, caching the result in an instance variable. Anyway, I like your starting code better, it's more readable than the one-liner, and can be shortened by couple of lines without losing readability.